# How to scale a texture so it appears smaller or larger on an object, during texture painting?

Tags: texturing

How can I change the texture to make it appear smaller on objects, or larger?

Comment: Are you using a brush texture or projecting a texture on the mesh?

Comment: I am using texture paint mode

Comment: Im still unsure what exactly the problem, can you describe the steps of what you are doing?

Comment: This sounds obvious to me. The texture chosen could be massive. Lets say you took a dalmatian dots texture to map your dog, but it showed up looking like a dairy cow. How do you scale the texture down to an appropriate size. What is confusing about this?

Answer (score 6):

From the way your question is worded, I think you want to scale the UVmap in the image editor.

Select your entire UVmap in the image editor, and scale it. a larger UV map will make the texture appear smaller and more repetitive, and a smaller UVmap will make the texture appear larger (and lower resolution)

[image]